# Trying to get Jupyter notebook to work with PySpark

Tags: pyspark, anaconda, jupyter

I am fairly new to this but I have followed numerous setup instructions and installed Anaconda to use the Jupyter notebook with PySpark. I've installed Python, PySpark, Winutils, set environment variables but still cannot get PySpark to work.
Everyone seems to have their own flavor of configurations.

```
When running this code:
import findspark
findspark.init()

import pyspark # only run after findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.sql('''select 'spark' as hello ''')
df.show()
```

...I get numerous errors ending with "TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)"

When I simply run:

```
import findspark

findspark.init()
```

...nothing happens at all.

I am trying to setup a local Jupyter notebook environment to test code for use in AWS Glue.

Adding type errors:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-84edcc0ab449> in <module>
      2 findspark.init()
      3 
----> 4 import pyspark # only run after findspark.init()
      5 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
      6 spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

C:\spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\__init__.py in <module>
     49 
     50 from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
---> 51 from pyspark.context import SparkContext
     52 from pyspark.rdd import RDD, RDDBarrier
     53 from pyspark.files import SparkFiles

C:\spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py in <module>
     29 from py4j.protocol import Py4JError
     30 
---> 31 from pyspark import accumulators
     32 from pyspark.accumulators import Accumulator
     33 from pyspark.broadcast import Broadcast, BroadcastPickleRegistry

C:\spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\accumulators.py in <module>
     95     import socketserver as SocketServer
     96 import threading
---> 97 from pyspark.serializers import read_int, PickleSerializer
     98 
     99 

C:\spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\serializers.py in <module>
     70     xrange = range
     71 
---> 72 from pyspark import cloudpickle
     73 from pyspark.util import _exception_message
     74 

C:\spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\cloudpickle.py in <module>
    143 
    144 
--> 145 _cell_set_template_code = _make_cell_set_template_code()
    146 
    147 

C:\spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\cloudpickle.py in _make_cell_set_template_code()
    124         )
    125     else:
--> 126         return types.CodeType(
    127             co.co_argcount,
    128             co.co_kwonlyargcount,

TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)
```

Comment: what version of spark and java is installed in your machine

Comment: Spark version 2.4.8 / Java version 1.8.0_241

Comment: If anyone can provide additional information about how configure PySpark to work within an Anaconda Jupyter notebook, it would be much appreciated.